Calculation of the diffusion coefficient of a Lennard-Jones fluid (liquid argon)
I'm trying to simulate with the code written by Professor Cameron Abrams(https://github.com/Abrams-Teaching/instructional-codes/blob/main/originals/mdlj_and.c), a set of argon atoms interacting via a Lennard
Jones potential coupled with a stochastic thermostat (Anderson or Dissipative particle dynamics). However when I try to calculate the self-diffusion coefficient from the Einstein relation, the result is totally different from that obtained by Rahman in his famous article ((https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.136.A405)). The condition of the simulation, which I've chosen, is after all, the same of Rahman's, that is 864 particles  at a density of 1.364 $\frac{g}{cm^3}$ and a temperature of 94.4 K. How is it possible this discrepancy? In reduced units, I obtain $5.27 \cdot 10^{-9}$, while the expected result is 0.0456(=$\frac{2,43 \cdot 10^{-5}}{\frac{\sigma^2}{time}}$). Is there anyone who has experience with molecular dynamics here? 

What are the units of their answer and your answer?

I'm adding an image to this question. to show the units.
